# Default values checked for custom column multi choices

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I am using sharepoint 2013 online, i created a custom column, with multiple selections checkboxes.

I would like to have some of the values in the choices menu to be default selected/checked.

[image]

How can i achieve it ?

Thanks for your helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Default Value` field, select `Calculated Value` and enter the following value in the text box:

```
=";#Contacts;#Customer Needs and Benefits;#"
```

Comment: Thanks alot, that is exactly what i am looking for :)